# Using read to simply short bash command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, streaming

I am trying to simplify a small command I use for some video streams I use.

I can successfully call the streamed video with the following:

```
livestreamer -p mpv --crunchyroll-username="USERNAME_HERE" --crunchyroll-password="PASSWORD_HERE" LINK_HERE --player-passthrough hls
```

I use my account info, and paste the video link. This opens the said stream in mpv and plays fine.

The bash script I am using to just call for the URL with read then complete is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter URL of Crunchyroll Video: " url

livestreamer -p mpv --crunchyroll-username="USERNAME_HERE" --crunchyroll-password="PASSWORD_HERE" $url --player-passthrough hls
```

However, this just does nothing, and outputs me back to a clean line. Is there something I am missing? I wonder if its possible that this is just exiting the whole command before it runs because it needs to be told to pass it on or something.

Comment: Well, aside from `$url` being unquoted nothing seems wrong. Try `"$url"`  in the `livestreamer` command. Anything fishy about the urls themselves ?

Comment: I was able to get livestreamer to attempt to start the stream by using quotes around $url and the actually link, but it would terminate itself before my video player would open. I am quessing it is a limitation of livestreamer itself. Since the program has the options to but the commands in its config its not a bug though, just the programs design.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I just figured this out.

I created a config for livestreamer and was able to store my values needed, even username and password.

Now i can just call what i need with "livestreamer URL_HERE", and it works as intended. No need for a bash script at all!

Comment: Good job then :)